# What file is the standard frontpage that lists all the posts?

Tags: posts, homepage, frontpage

I want to edit something in my theme but i can't find the file that lists all the blogposts on the homepage. In the 'Reading' settings i have: Front page displays - your latests posts as the chosen option. When i edit index.php i cannot see the changes so that is not it. So what phpfile does wordpress use to generate 'your latest posts' ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I figured it out...i had the WP Super Cache plugin installed so i couldn't see any changes i was making. So disabling that worked out!

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png this shows the WP structure I hope it helps you out in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Glad you got it sorted out, but to answer your original question:

1) The `front-page.php` template file, if it exists, will be used to generate Front Page content, whether the Front Page is set to display the blog posts index or a static Page.

2) The `home.php` template file, if it exists, will be used to generate the blog posts Index, whether the blog posts index is displayed on the Front Page or on another static Page. (Note: `front-page.php` has priority over `home.php` for the Front Page.)

3) If neither of these template files exist, then `index.php` is used to generate the blog posts index, whether the blog posts index is displayed on the Front Page or on another static Page.